# Dart - The setter 'someVar' is not defined for the class 'Map'

Tags: dart, dart2js

I'm trying to 'port' some script to the Dart. To learn how everything work etc.
But there is a problem - in JavaScript we can set and get any variable in the object.
In Dart we have a Map class. And I have no idea how to use it (there is not so many help from Dart API Reference).
Currently I have:

```
Map settings;
//Then I get an dynamic result of a function that gives either null or object.
settings = result ?? {};
settings.someVar = 5;
```

And this code produces the following error:

```
"The setter 'someVar' is not defined for the class 'Map'."
```

Of course I can just 'invent' a new class `Settings`, but is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `Map`, you get and put values with the `[]` and `[]=` operators. So in this case you would use it like so;

```
settings['someVar'] = 5;
```

You can also use the `addAll` method;

```
settings.addAll({'someVar': 5, 'someOtherVar': 10});
```

*Dart API References: [operator []](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html), [operator []=](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-core/Map/operator_put.html), [addAll](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.0/dart-core/Map/addAll.html)*